# Не появляется кнопка меню при клике

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Кнопка меню из трех полосок - при клике появляется само меню, у него прозрачный бекграунд, поэтому убрал первую кнопку (чтобы не светилась позади) когда появляется само меню, но вот сделать обратно, чтобы кнопка появлялась когда меню скрывается не получается, подскажите что не так

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "367px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

function hideButton() {
  document.getElementById("hideButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showButton() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("showButton[0]").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
.menu li {
  min-width: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 1rem;
  color: #acc;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(35, 176, 56, 0.3);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul onclick="openNav(), hideButton()" id="hideButton">
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav(), showButton()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

в консоли ошибка

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visibility' of undefined`

из за того, что `getElementsByClassName` возвращает не один элемент как я понял, 2 `id` присвоить одному элементу не получится тоже я так понимаю) поэтому приходится использовать класс, но вот с тем что он возвращает разобраться нужно, или можно еще какими то способами такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимость надо менять у того же элемента, который скрывали.
`setTimeout()` нужен для того, чтобы кнопки не накладывались друг на друга.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "367px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

function hideButton() {
  document.getElementById("hideButton").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function showButton() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("hideButton").style.visibility = "visible";
   }, 300)
}
```

```css
.menu li {
  min-width: 6px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 1rem;
  color: #acc;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(35, 176, 56, 0.3);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul onclick="openNav(), hideButton()" id="hideButton">
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
    <li> &#9776;</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav(), showButton()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Забыл что в jQuery есть встроенные методы для скрывания/отображения, можно гораздо проще и короче написать:

function openNav() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width", "367px");
}

function closeNav() {
  $("#mySidenav").css("width", "0");
}

function hideButton() {
 $("#hideButton").hide();
}

function showButton() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $("#hideButton").show();
}, 450);
}

Comment: @chase, да, jQuery даёт возможность писать более простой код, но при её использовании сайт проигрывает в производительности. Поэтому знать, как написать решение на чистом JS, никогда не помешает.

Comment: а что не так с производительностью в jQuery?)